# Shell: replacing file text loop using sed and lines numbers

Tags: shell, sed

I have two files.

The first file contains, in each line, line number and text. For example:

```
2   AAAA
4   BBBB
5   nnnn
```

this text should replace the lines in the second file - according to the first column which is the line number on the second file.

So if initially the second files was:

```
XXXXX
XXXXX
XXXXX
XXXXX
XXXXX
XXXXX
```

after the change, it would be

```
XXXXX
AAAA
XXXXX
BBBB
nnnn
XXXXX
```

I thought using sed :

```
sed "$Ns/XXXXX/$A/" file > file-after-change
```

while `$N` is the line number (taken from the first file) and `$A` will be the string from the first file.

How can i read the line number first as variable `N` and the string itself to a different variable (`A`)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sed` to transform the first file into a `sed` script, and then pass that to a second `sed` instance.

```
sed 's%^\([0-9]*\) *\([^ ]*\)$%\1s/XXXXX/\2/' firstfile |
sed -f - secondfile
```

Linux `sed` will happily accept `-f -`; on some other platforms, maybe experiment with `-f /dev/stdin` or just save the generated script to a temporary file, and delete it when you are done.

Comment: Wow, the trick of piping `sed`'s output to `sed -f` is amazing. Never thought of it! (My solution is just the ugly version of yours :D)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, consider to use `awk`.

```sh
awk 'FNR==NR { seen[$1]=$2; next } seen[FNR] { print seen[FNR]; next } 1' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\s\+/c/' file1 | sed -f - file2
```

Turn file1 into a sed script and apply it to file2.

The sed script changes each line in file2 referenced by a line number in file1 to the argument following that line number.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a potential solution that edits the "second.txt" file 'in place' and is along the lines of what you've already tried:

```
cat first.txt
2   AAAA
4   BBBB
5   nnnn

cat second.txt
XXXXX
XXXXX
XXXXX
XXXXX
XXXXX
XXXXX

# GNU sed
while read N A
do
    sed -i "${N}s/XXXXX/${A}/" second.txt
done < first.txt

cat second.txt
XXXXX
AAAA
XXXXX
BBBB
nnnn
XXXXX
```

(macOS sed: `while read N A; do sed -i '' "${N}s/XXXXX/${A}/" second.txt; done < first.txt`)

Answer (score 0):

Ugly but working (`guide` is the file with line numbers and substitutions, `input` is the actual input file):

```sh
eval "$(cat guide | sed '/^[0-9]\+ */s!^\([0-9]\+\) *\(.*\)!\1s/.*/\2/!' | sed -z "s/\n/;/g;s/.*/sed '&'/")" < input
```

(Requires GNU sed, I belive.)